# How can my default locale be taken into account by the Swing components?

Tags: java, swing, locale

My default locale is French, but the components in my app are still in English.

```
System.out.println(UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getDefaultLocale()); // => fr_FR
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.language")); // => fr
```

For example, my `JFileChooser`:

[image: JFileChooser]

What's the problem? Is there a way to force the components language value?

I'm using Java 11, Eclipse, Windows 7.

Comment: I think you have to check if the locale of the `JComponent`s is *FRENCH*: `JComponent.getDefaultLocale();` — if not, then set it before you instantiate them: `JComponent.setDefaultLocale(Locale.FRENCH);`

Comment: @deHaar yes the default locale is already "fr", for JComponent and also for my JFileChooser object, but the dialog is still in english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JFileChooser uses as a content pane `sun.swing.FilePane`. If you take a look at `installDefaults()` method of [this class](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/swing/FilePane.java) you will find the following comment:

```
 // TODO: On windows, get the following localized strings from the OS
```

Which means it is not implemented yet (and I don't think it will ever be).

So, the only thing you can do (unfortunately) is to change them manually using `UIManager` keys:

```
FileChooser.viewMenuLabelText
FileChooser.refreshActionLabelText
FileChooser.newFolderActionLabelText
FileChooser.listViewActionLabelText
FileChooser.detailsViewActionLabelText
FileChooser.fileSizeKiloBytes
FileChooser.fileSizeMegaBytes
FileChooser.fileSizeGigaBytes
FileChooser.renameErrorTitleText
FileChooser.renameErrorText
FileChooser.renameErrorFileExistsText
FileChooser.lookInLabelText
FileChooser.fileNameLabelText
FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText
FileChooser.upFolderToolTipText
FileChooser.newFolderToolTipText
FileChooser.viewMenuButtonToolTipText
FileChooser.saveButtonText
FileChooser.openButtonText
FileChooser.cancelButtonText
FileChooser.updateButtonText
FileChooser.helpButtonText
FileChooser.directoryOpenButtonText
FileChooser.saveButtonToolTipText
FileChooser.openButtonToolTipText
FileChooser.cancelButtonToolTipText
FileChooser.updateButtonToolTipText
FileChooser.helpButtonToolTipText
FileChooser.directoryOpenButtonToolTipText
FileChooser.saveDialogTitleText
FileChooser.openDialogTitleText
```

For example:

```
//google translate :)
UIManager.put("FileChooser.newFolderActionLabelText", "créer un nouveau dossier");
```

And there is also the method [JFileChoose#setApproveButtonText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setApproveButtonText(java.lang.String)), but I do not think this covers your needs.

Comment: do you know why it is the only thing  I can do ? and why my locale is not taken into account ?

Answer (score 0):

JFileChooser.setDefaultLocale(Locale.getDefault());

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: You can manually set JFileChooser's locale via JFileChooser.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("fr","FR"));